# (Mac)Vim: when opening a file, Vim shows the file name and Press ENTER to continue

Tags: vim, macvim, spf13vim

When entering vim by opening a file directly, I get the text shown below - which is (in this case, duplicated) text showing the name of the file with a message saying "Press ENTER or type command to continue".  I'm using SPF-13, and not sure what could be causing this.  Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: `I'm using SPF-13, and not sure what could be causing this` if you were using vim and config it by yourself, you know what causes this.

Comment: Thanks, Kent.  Yes, I have my own .vimrc.local, so I'll take a look into it.  Thanks!